# Find the area of a region using monte carlo methods

Tags: spatial

I am interested in finding the area of the dark gray region, in r I have used the area function of spatstat package but is very time consuming since I need to run a mh algorithm, I have read that I can calculate this area using monte carlo approach but  I do not know how to proceed, please someone can help me?

[image]

some code example from spatstat book for the plot and for the area:

```
    source("figurelayout.R")
source("startup.R")
llibrary(spatstat)


requireversion(spatstat, "1.41-1.073")

W <- as.owin(swedishpines)
x <- c(28,29,55,60,66)
y <- c(70,38,32,72,59)
X <- ppp(x=x,y=y, window = W)
u <- list(x=48,y=50)
u <- as.ppp(u, W)
rad <- 14
Xplusr <- dilation(X, rad) # 
uplusr <- disc(rad, u) #bola de radio rad con centro en u
ovlap <- intersect.owin(uplusr, Xplusr)
B<-setminus.owin( disc( rad, c(u$x, u$y) ), Xplusr)
AIdemo <- layered(W, 
                  ovlap,
                  Xplusr,
                  uplusr,
                  X,
                  u,B)
layerplotargs(AIdemo) <- list(list(),
                              list(col="darkgrey", border=NA),
                              list(lwd=2),
                              list(lwd=2, lty=2),
                              list(pch=16),
                              list(pch=3),
                              list(col="red", border=NA))



###################################################
### code chunk number 98: Unit.Rnw:3-5
###################################################
newplot(6, 0.7)
setmargins(0)



###################################################
### code chunk number 99: 13gibbs.Rnw:3214-3215
###################################################
plot(AIdemo, main="")
plot(setminus.owin( disc( rad, c(u$x, u$y) ), Xplusr))

area<-area(B)
```

Comment: I don't have the time to write a proper answer but here is a tip: if you scatter points uniformly on that surface, the proportion of those points that fall within your region of interest is proportional to its area

Comment: I would recommend to use a *quasi-Monte Carlo* method, if you can't do some more serious numerical integration approach. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Monte_Carlo_method

Comment: Since there exist accurate methods to compute the area directly from the internal representation of the region (either in raster or vector format), could you explain why you wish to employ the much less accurate and computationally more expensive MC method?

Comment: First of all, is this [tag:self-study]?

Comment: Also, is this really on-topic?

Comment: Something like this is used when simulating the area interaction Gibbs model in `spatstat`. What kind of mh (Metropolis-Hastings?) algorithm are you using it for if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking is a simple Monte Carlo application. You will need to draw uniform samples across the whole region, and check the proportion of points selected within your region.

To check if a point lies within the region, you can describe your region with the center-radius form of the circle equation (your region is just a circle).

Follow the link:

> http://geekyisawesome.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/montecarlo-method-of-finding-area-of.html

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKS]

Answer (score 0):

Your question title suggests that you want to use Monte Carlo, but the question itself just says "I am interested in finding the area of the dark gray region ...". Another way to calculate this area in `spatstat` is to use the function `areaLoss`.

Continuing your example (which I guess is really copyrighted example code from the companion website of the `spatstat` book):

```
Y <- superimpose(u, X) # Centres of all circles
areaLoss(Y, rad, exact = TRUE) # Remaining area in each circle
areaLoss(Y, rad, exact = TRUE, subset = 1) # Only circle of interest
```

Depending on how many overlapping circles you have this may be faster than what you currently are doing. Also depending on the number of circles setting `exact = FALSE` may be faster.

If you really wanted to estimate the area of `B` by simple Monte Carlo it can be done in a few lines of code:

```
Bbox <- as.rectangle(B)
points <- runifpoint(1000, Bbox)
insideB <- inside.owin(points, w = B)
fraction <- mean(insideB)
area(Bbox) * fraction
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks you for your comments, here is the code for the solution :)

```
x.min <- min(W$xrange[1])
x.max <- max(W$xrange[2])
y.min <- min(W$yrange[1])
y.max <- max(W$yrange[2])

n.sims <- 1000
random.points <- data.frame(Q=runif(n=n.sims,x.min,x.max),
                            DOC=runif(n=n.sims,y.min,y.max))
random.points<-data.frame(Xinterval=runif(n=n.sims,x.min,x.max),Yinterval=runif(n=n.sims,y.min,y.max))
contador<-0
for ( ii in 1:n.sims ) {
  if(inside.owin(random.points$Xinterval[ii], random.points$Yinterval[ii], w=B)
  ){
      contador<-contador+1
  }
}
estimatedArea<-area(W)*contador/n.sims
```

Comment: I do not use R, but 1000 calls to `inside.owin` is really faster than 1 call to `area.owin`?

Comment: you right, I realized that area() is faster than the monte Carlo approach, I am having troubles since I am doing mh and each iteration is taking sooo long :(

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) for speed issues, profiling is always a good idea. 2) Try posting a question about your [underlying problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).